# Using CIColorMap on iOS, kCIInputGradientImageKey unavailable

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

I am attempting to use a Core Image CIColorMap filter in my iOS app, but it seems that the constant key value (kCIInputGradientImageKey) for setting the gradient image is marked as unavailable on iOS in CIFilter.h.

The core image documentation states that CIColorMap is available as of iOS 6.0, and I can actually get it to work by setting the gradient image using my own string key constant @"inputGradientImage".

Is there a different key constant value that I should be using?

This just seems like a bug in the CIFilter.h header file, but thought I'd check before reporting it.

Comment: Just use inputGradientImage.

Comment: Yah, already doing that to work around it. I'll open a bug with Apple.